# Enable Nvidia Dynamic Super Resolution for non-native resolution?

Tags: resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-dsr

I use a projector (Epson 2040) as my main gaming display.

The native resolution is 1080p@60hz. By enabling the projector's 3D mode, and disabling 3D vision, I can also run games in 720p@120Hz.

I'd like to use DSR when I play at 720p. Is there a way to enable it for non-native resolutions? Can I fool the driver into thinking that 720p is my native resolution?

Posted this on Nvidia forum as well:
https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/998615/geforce-drivers/enable-dynamic-super-resolution-for-non-native-resolutions-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to download CRU (Custom Resolution Utility) and delete all resolutions higher than 720p.
Moving between different edid-settings is a major pain though.

Comment: Where can one download CRU?

Comment: You can find it here: https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU

Comment: Remember that every single other resolution needs to be removed for it to work.

Comment: I have not tried it yet but this sounds legit.